# Personal account disabled - Only administrator for app with 10k+ users

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

My personal Facebook account has been disabled (due to 'repeat copyright infringement' but that's another issue I need to discuss with Facebook as we keep having things removed we are in fact allowed to use)

The big problem is we have apps created by my personal account which is a developer account and since being disabled nobody can log in to our apps as it says the apps have also been disabled.

Can someone at Facebook please help me with finding a solution to this, not necessarily reinstating my account which would be perfect but I appreciate I need to speak to someone regarding the reason for termination, but perhaps make one of the test users an administrator for the apps if this will solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: stackoverflow is for third party developers, i don´t think you will get facebook support here...

Comment: I am a third party developer and this is a question regarding Facebook login for our apps no longer working due to my personal account being disabled without an additional administrator, so there is now no way of accessing our developer account. I think it's perfectly reasonable to have posted here, especially since there is no other way of contacting Facebook developer support, but thanks for taking the time to comment.